# Convolution formula proof- Random discrete varaiables

Tags: probability, random-variables, generating-functions

Let X, Y be discrete random variables and
take values at $1, 2, · · · , n, · · · $

$f_{X}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{k=inf} P(X=k)x^{k}$ is the probability generating function.

and this result was given below

$f_{X+Y}(x)=f_{X}(x). f_{Y}(x)$

Can someone explain me how they reached to this formula which is known as convolution formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if $X,Y$ are independent. If $X,Y$ are independent, then $$f_{X+Y}(z)=E[z^{(X+Y)}] = E[z^{X}z^{Y}] = E[z^{X}] E[z^{Y}] = f_X(t)f_Y(t).$$

The "convolution formula" is usually just referring to the distribution of $Z = X+Y$ when $X,Y$ are independent. In this case
$$
P_Z(k) = P[Z=k] =\sum_{i} P[X=i, Y=k-i] = \sum_i P[X=i] P[Y=k-i] = (P_X * P_Y)(k).
$$

Answer (score 2):

For any sequences $\{a_k\}_{k\ge 0}$ and $\{b_j\}_{j\ge 0}$ we can define the ordinary power generating function

$$G_a(t)=\sum_k a_k t^k,\text{ and }G_b(t)=\sum_j b_j t^j$$

If we now define the sequence $\{c_h:c_h=\sum_{\{j+k=h\}}a_{h-j}b_j\}_{h\ge0}$ then it generating function will be

$$G_c(t)=G_a(t)G_b(t)$$

This is just a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). Apply it to the case of the multiplication of the generating functions for the mass function of independent random variables and you get the generating function of the sum.